# Trajectary for a buoy flow in the tasman sea with tail

Tags: python-3.x, animation

Im trying to make a plot the path of a buoy in the tasman sea. 
I got the buoy flowing around but I cannot find how i can give it a tail of the previous 5 steps.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# plot the map relative to time 0 using, instead of plt.contourf, ax.contourf:
ssh_map = ax.contourf(sshlon,sshlat,np.transpose(ssh[:,:,0]))
# add a colorbar with
plt.colorbar(ssh_map)

def animate(t):
    ax.clear()
    # plot the map relative to time t, also with ax.contourf
    ax.contourf(sshlon,sshlat,np.transpose(ssh[:,:,t]))
    # Save the location of the buoy in t 
    I=np.where(buoytime==sshtime[t])
    # plot the location of the bouy
    ax.scatter(buoylon[I], buoylat[I], c='r')
    # add an appropriate title and axes with
    ax.set_title('Movie SSH')
    ax.set_xlabel('Longitude')
    ax.set_ylabel('Latitude')
    return ax
# start animation
anim = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=77)


plt.show()
```

Comment: You could slice the current location plus the five previous locations from the data, e.g. for step `i` you plot `data[i-5:i]`. You need to handle beginning and end of the data.

Answer (score 0):

You could slice the current location plus the five previous locations from the data, e.g. for step `i` you plot `data[i:i+5]`. You need to handle beginning and end of the data.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

# First set up the figure, the axis, and the plot element we want to animate
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(0, 2), ylim=(-2, 2))
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

ax.set_xlim(0, 100)

x = np.arange(100)
y = np.random.rand(100)

# initialization function: plot the background of each frame
def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

# animation function.  This is called sequentially
def animate(i):

    _x = x[i: i+5]
    _y = y[i: i+5]
    print(_x,_y)
    line.set_data(_x, _y)
    return line,

# call the animator.  blit=True means only re-draw the parts that have changed.
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=200, interval=20, blit=True)


plt.show()
```

Example from https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2012/08/18/matplotlib-animation-tutorial/