# Plotting an array of arrays crashes matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have an array of the shape (6416,17,3). I am trying to plot each entry (17,3) after each other in a 3D grid as if it's a video. This is the code I wrote for the visualizer function:

```
def draw_limbs_3d(ax, joints_3d, limb_parents):
    # ax.clear()
    for i in range(joints_3d.shape[0]):
        x_pair = [joints_3d[i, 0], joints_3d[limb_parents[i], 0]]
        y_pair = [joints_3d[i, 1], joints_3d[limb_parents[i], 1]]
        z_pair = [joints_3d[i, 2], joints_3d[limb_parents[i], 2]]
        ax.plot(x_pair, y_pair, zs=z_pair, linewidth=3)

def visualizer(joints_3d):
    joint_parents = [16, 15, 1, 2, 3, 1, 5, 6, 14, 8, 9, 14, 11, 12, 14, 14, 1]
    fig = plt.figure('3D Pose')
    ax_3d = plt.axes(projection='3d')
    plt.ion()
    ax_3d.clear()
    ax_3d.clear()
    ax_3d.view_init(-90, -90)
    ax_3d.set_xlim(-1000, 1000)
    ax_3d.set_ylim(-1000, 1000)
    ax_3d.set_zlim(0, 4000)
    ax_3d.set_xticks([])
    ax_3d.set_yticks([])
    ax_3d.set_zticks([])
    white = (1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0)
    ax_3d.w_xaxis.set_pane_color(white)
    ax_3d.w_yaxis.set_pane_color(white)
    ax_3d.w_xaxis.line.set_color(white)
    ax_3d.w_yaxis.line.set_color(white)
    ax_3d.w_zaxis.line.set_color(white)
    draw_limbs_3d(ax_3d, joints_3d, joint_parents)
```

and I use this code to run on all entries:

```
joints_3d = np.load('output.npy')
for joint in joints_3d:
    joint = joint.reshape((17,3))
    visualizer(joint)
```

which causes the program to crash. It works for one array though and I get the correct plot. I would be grateful if you could help me. Thank you.

Comment: In case you are trying to show 6416 figures at once, this will sure crash your computer. (Usually you would get a warning after 20 figures already.) If you want to do an animation, google for "matplotlib 3d animation".

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I will try that, do you think I can apply it to these functions?

Comment: Yes. Make sure to only create a single figure and update everything inside of it.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Ok thank you very much

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59308335/7919597 with a small modification should work